# (jQueryUI) Highlight new AJAX UL entry without loosing image bullet point

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an ajax list that updates (as notifications). However, what I'm trying to do is jQuery UI Hightlight to show a new `<li>` that is appended to the `<ul>...</ul>`. The `<li>` however has a image bullet point which disappears for the duration of the highlight.

Is there any way to highlight the entire `<li> ... </li>` include the bullet point itself.

What I assume happens is a background is added to the `<li>` for the duration of the hightlight which then overrides the bullet point background.

**jQuery**

```
$(data).hide().prependTo("ul.notifications").fadeIn("slow", function() {  
    $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);  
});
```

**CSS**

```
ul li.standard {  
    font-size : 1.1em;  
    font-weight:700;  
    color : #555;  
    list-style:none;  
    padding:0 0 0 40px;  
    margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;  
    background: url(../images/bullet_arrow.png) no-repeat 0px 5px;  
}
```

Comment: How are you making the image bullet? Using a CSS background image or "list-style-image:"?

Comment: Updated original, using background

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731807/how-do-i-use-the-highlight-jquery-effect-without-temporarily-hiding-the-backgro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question up, I managed to resolve the issue using the link provided by cnanney:

[How do I use the "highlight" jquery effect without temporarily hiding the background-image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731807/how-do-i-use-the-highlight-jquery-effect-without-temporarily-hiding-the-backgro)